# How does SetWindowPos affect the owner window's Z order?

Tags: windows, winapi

[The `SetWindowPos` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) accepts the following flag:

> **SWP_NOOWNERZORDER** (0x0200)
> Does not change the owner window's position in the Z order.

What *does* the `SetWindowPos` function do to the owner window's position in the Z order, if you do not pass this flag?

Answer (score 7):

> What does the SetWindowPos function do to the owner window's position
> in the Z order, if you do not pass this flag?

Take placing the owned window at the bottom of the Z order for an example. There are three windows: Owned, TestWindowPos (owner) and New Tab Chrome window (as a reference).

Test code piece:

```
   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   HWND hWndOwned = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, L"Owned", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
       0, 0, 500, 500, hWnd, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   ShowWindow(hWndOwned, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWndOwned);

   SetWindowPos(hWndOwned, HWND_BOTTOM, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
```

When `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER` flag is set you can see from the following snapshot that it puts the owned window at bottom but keep the owner unchanged.

[image]

When `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER` flag is **not** set you can see from the following snapshot that **it changes the owned window's z-order together with the owner window's**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a test program which tries all SetWindowPos operations in each possible starting order of 4 windows (owner, 2 owned windows, and an unrelated window). I found the following:

- Windows prefers to put owned windows directly in front of their owner, without any other windows between them.
- When `SWP_NOACTIVATE` and `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER` are used together, you can put windows in any order you like. The previous "rule" is not enforced, ever.
- When `SWP_NOACTIVATE` is *not* used, the targeted window becomes *active*. The targeted window is always moved to the front of the Z-order, as the documentation states in "Remarks" - `hWndInsertAfter` is ignored except for special values.

  If the targeted window is an owned window or an owner, the preferred Z-order *is* enforced for that owner and *all* its owned windows. `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER` is ignored.
- When `SWP_NOACTIVATE` is used and `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER` is not used, and the targeted window is an owned window or an owner, Windows *may* decide to enforce the preferred order for that owner and all its owned windows. The criteria for this decision seem to be as follows (though I would not rely on them):

  - The targeted window is an owner, or
  - The targeted window is owned and is active, or
  - The call attempts to put an owned window behind its owner